# How to keep the PowerShell process alive after closing powershell terminal in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, bitbucket-pipelines

I need to run a PowerShell command in windows PowerShell, its running fine as expected. The problem is when I close the Windows PowerShell terminal, it kills the process, whereas I want the process to continue running forever.

Is there a way to close the terminal and have process working in the background.

Here is my command that I need to run:

```
.\start.ps1 -accountUuid '{XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX}' `
-repositoryUuid '{XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX}' `
-runnerUuid '{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX}' `
-OAuthClientId XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX `
-OAuthClientSecret XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX `
-workingDirectory '..\temp'
```

Comment: Use a scheduled task

Comment: Or see if you can work the logic into [start-job](https://ss64.com/ps/start-job.html) to get the desired result.

Comment: How is this related to the bitbucket-pipelines tag?

Comment: @N1ngu This is for setting up self hosted BitBucket runner.
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/adding-a-new-runner-in-bitbucket/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the command `Start-process` with option `-NoNewWindow` to run the process in the background. Add all your arguments in `-ArgumentList`.

```
Start-Process -FilePath ".\start.ps1" -ArgumentList "-accountUuid ...", "-repositoryUuid ..." -NoNewWindow
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3)